# The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization, jsonserializer, json-serialization

Before serialize -

```
 "welcomePageConfig": {
        "welcomeTitleText": {
            "style": {
                "color": "#FFFFFF"
            },
            "content": {
                "sv": "Välkommen",
                "en": "Welcome"
            }
        }
```

I use JsonSerializer to deserialize below string to an object.

```
string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(welcomePageConfig);
```

After serialize -

```
{\"WelcomeTitleText\":{\"Style\":{\"Color\":\"#FFFFFF\"},\"Content\":[{\"Key\":\"sv\",\"Value\":\"Välkommen\"},{\"Key\":\"en\",\"Value\":\"Welcome\"}]}

welcomePageConfig = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WelcomePageConfig>(jsonString);
```

When I try to deserialize, it gives me an error mentioning
**"The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]."**

It pops after "{"Key...." this part. Since it's a dictionary.

```
public class WelcomePageConfig
    {
        [JsonProperty("welcomeTitleText")]
        public StylingComponent WelcomeTitleText { get; set; }
    }

public class StylingComponent
    {
        [JsonProperty("style")]
        public Style Style { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("content")]
        public Dictionary<string, string> Content { get; set; }
    }
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Please show your `WelcomePageConfig` class implementation.

Comment: that list of objects that you point to is not a dictionary; Dictionary item has Key and Value properties not Key1 Value, Key2 Value, Key3 Value; Name of property cannot change unless you will write a custom converter that will ignore the number in the name and build the dictionary.

Comment: There are two ways to serialise a dictionary, either as an array of key-value pairs, or as an json "object" notation. You have an array of key value pairs. To answer the question we need to see the definition of WelcomePageConfig.

Comment: @Rafal Sorry I copied the wrong json. Now I updated with the correct one. It contains Key and Value not Key1 and Key2

Comment: @Ben I updated the question with more insights

Comment: @Hash_Dew What means "Before serialize " ? Why data is different ?  Should be the same .  Can you show how do you serialize it pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite a common convention that `Dictionary<string, ...>` is handled as JSON object during (de)serialization, this convention for example is supported by both `System.Text.Json` and Newtonsoft's Json.NET. It seems that at some point during serialization something is going not as expected (you have not shown your serialization code) and the `Content` is handled like `IEnumerable` (of key-value pairs) not as `Dictionary`, so you need to change the model for deserialization:

```cs
public class StylingComponent
{
    // ...
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is the serialing code - 

string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(welcomePageConfig);

After using keyValuePairs it doesn't give any errors but not deserializing. Objects set to null after deserializing.

Comment: @Hash_Dew there is no serialize code - only deserialization one: `welcomePageConfig = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<WelcomePageConfig>>(jsonString);` .

Comment: Just updated the question with that code. Please take a look.

Comment: @Hash_Dew check out [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jTqlrx). Your update does not make sense - JSON  contains a single object while you are trying to deserialize to a collection.

Comment: @Hash_Dew `JsonPropertyAttribute` is attribute from Newtonsoft Json.NET  and will be ignored by `JsonSerializer.Deserialize`.

Comment: I tried to simplify the issue to make more easy to understand and made some mess there. Anyway inbuild json serializer didn't work for me. But I used newtonsoft serializer then it worked. Thanks alot for the help.